# Pitching own tents at Sambhar lake in Rajasthan?

Tags: india, camping, rajasthan

I have seen pictures of Sambhar lake and it looks like a place where I would like to take my own tent and spend a night or two so I was wondering if this is allowed at Sambhar lake. I searched a lot but there is no such information anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no notices posted any where at Sambhar lake that you can or cannot pitch tents there. There is [no police or authority present at Sambhar lake](https://www.indiatravelforum.in/threads/sambhar-salt-lake-jaipur-rajasthan.253/#post-9629) to prevent you from doing that either.

Legally speaking it is government land and is part of a wild life reserve and you are not allowed to pitch tents there.

My advise to you would be to pitch your tents near the Sambhari devi temple where there is a small shop as well and a few people live there including the priest and his family so just talk to them and let them know what you intend to do. Sambhri temple also has a small parking area where they may allow you to pitch your tent as that is where I parked through the night as "Neel gai" roam on the lake bed even at night besides some other animals.